# How to Increase K3s Default Storage Space

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, storage, k3s, rhel8

I'm running into an issue where the image I'm trying to load into K3s is too large, giving me disk space errors. I can see in df -h there appear to be many mounts points for k3s and containerd on an overlay file system that is 5G and even after pruning with crictl does not have enough space to load my image. How do you increase this particular storage space?

I've tried looking at standard Linux resizing options (RHEL 8 here) but they don't seem to recognize the overlay file system name and I don't see an underlying file path anywhere.

I've checked various config files for k3s and can't seem to pinpoint any place where this value is set on creation or configured after the fact. Much of the documentation from K3s seems to focus on configured storage space inside the containers themselves rather than the k3s installation itself.

There seems to be a way to do this with docker and k3s on other answers but I'm not using docker for this installation so the commands obviously don't work to expand the storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming back to this, I found the appropriate volume to increase to get more k3s space. There are a bunch of mounts to the overlay File System with k3s file paths and all shared the same size and usage stats. Another volume that didn't appear to be related also had the same size and usage stats so by chance I increased it and it increased the overlay storage size as well giving me enough space to load my image.

The path was /dev/mapper/vg_root-varvol mounted at /var and using standard Linux commands I was able to increase the allocated space.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem: In a VM with two disks (10G (1.5G free) mounted at `/`, 200G (empty) mounted at `/mnt`). The overall free disk space for all overlay FSes was limited to 1.5G.

The solution to allow overlayfs (which was my primary concern) and k3s in general to use the second disk was rather simple: "Move" the directory `/var/lib/rancher` to the larger disk:

```bash
$ systemctl stop k3s
$ kill <list of containerd/kubelet/... PIDs that are still running>
$ mv /var/lib/rancher /mnt/
$ cat /etc/fstab
...
UUID=...     /mnt              ext4 defaults      0 1
/mnt/rancher /var/lib/rancher/ none defaults,bind 0 0
$ mount /var/lib/rancher/
$ systemctl start k3s
```